# Undefined ReactiveVar

Tags: meteor

I am trying to implement JQuery slider in one of my forms, and I use a ReactiveVar to track it's value

Code:

```
Template.requestPaymentForm.created = function() {
  this.requestAmountValue = new ReactiveVar(0);
};

Template.requestPaymentForm.helpers({
  selectedRequestAmount: function() {
    var value = Template.instance().requestAmountValue.get() / 100;
    return value;
  },
...
Template.requestPaymentForm.events({
  'slide #requestAmountSlider': function(event, template) {
    var sliderValue = template.$("#requestAmountSlider").slider("option","value");
    template.requestAmountValue.set(sliderValue);
  },
});
```

HTML

```
<template name='requestPaymentForm'>
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">Request Payment</h4>
    </div>
    {{#autoForm collection="Payments" id="insertPaymentForm" type="method" meteormethod="createPayment"}}
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="amounts">
          <span class="selected amount">Amount: {{formatMoney selectedRequestAmount}}</span>
          <span class="available amount">Available: {{formatMoney availableForRequest}}</span>
        </div>
        <br>

        <div id="requestAmountSlider"></div><br>

        {{> afFieldInput name='amount'}}
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button id="submitRequestPaymentForm" type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </div>
    {{/autoForm}}
  </div>
</template>
```

However, when I render this template, I get an error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
    at Object.Template.requestPaymentForm.helpers.selectedRequestAmount
```

Any idea as to why this is?

Much appreciated

Comment: This is a known bug we are working on right now: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/3540

Comment: @stubailo the bug is from autoform plugin, All the initializations from Template.requestPaymentForm.created are forfeited

Comment: Maybe - I should check. @tarlen: can you make a reproduction of this in the form of a cloneable app on github? then I can test my fix on it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug from Autoform plugin. All the initialization from your **Template.requestPaymentForm.created** is forfeited, and overwritten by Autoform .created . Thus, it said that the variable is undefined in helper.

I encounter the same problem and I am waiting for autoform team to fix this issue. My fix is adding a check in helper and assign value if it is null.Hope this helps.